# Как сохранить на сервер альбом фотографий от юзера Python Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой: Как сохранить все фотографии отправленные боту на сервере
Пробовал способ с этого [решения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200579/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC)
Но способ оказался не рабочим. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все отправленные ранее изображения никак нельзя вывести (если память мне не изменяет), но можно сохранять отправленные юзером изображения.

Чтоб сохранить изображение на сервере Telegram - его сначала нужно загрузить, и затем получить его идентификатор. Telegram высылает для одного изображения несколько идентификаторов, последний имеет наибольшее разрешение. Идентификатор нужно где-то хранить, его можно записать, например, в базу данных.
Как получить этот идентификатор, привожу ниже:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram import Bot

bot = Bot('token')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
async def get_photo(message):
    file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
    print(file_id) # этот идентификатор нужно где-то сохранить
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Это распечатает идентификатор, и сразу же отправит его вам уже из сервера Telegram

Если же нужно скачать именно на локальный компьютер, то вот код попроще:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram import Bot

bot = Bot('token')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
async def get_photo(message):
    file_info = await bot.get_file(message.photo[-1].file_id)
    await message.photo[-1].download(file_info.file_path.split('photos/')[1]) # ++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: Я уже знаю как сохранять фотографию, но этот код сохраняет только одну фотографию, а мне нужно сразу альбом фотографий

Comment: @ФрэнкФрэнкович, исправил. Теперь скачивает каждое отправленное изображение