# Как сохранить все фото, видео или документ от пользователя в папку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Я пишу бота на `Python` библиотека `aiogram`.
Вопрос следующий, я использую машину состояний для составления заказа, мне нужно на определенном этапе машины данные файлы(фото,видео,документ) из альбома сохранять в папку с ботом в формате `photos/сегодняшняя дата/файл` я пробовал решить данный вопрос с помощью [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1299129/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-python-aiogram) решения, но к сожалению оно не работает. Проблема у меня похожая, я использую метод `download`, но он сохраняет только 1 фото в папку.
Вот код:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=content_types=types.ContentType.ANY, state=FSMAdmin.photo)
async def load_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext, album: List[types.Message]):
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        date = f"{datetime.date.today()}"
        #message.photo[-1].file_unique_id
        path = os.path.join('photos', date, message.photo[-1].file_unique_id + '.jpg')
        await message.photo[-1].download(destination_file=path)
        print('Фото сохранены на сервер!')
    elif message.content_type == 'video':
        video = message.video.file_id
        date = f"{datetime.date.today()}"
        path = os.path.join('photos', date, video + '.mp4')
        await message.video.download(destination_file=path)
        print('Видео сохранено на сервер!')
        #await message.reply('Видео успешно добавлено!')
    elif message.content_type == 'document':
        doc = message.document.file_id
        date = f"{datetime.date.today()}"
        path = os.path.join('photos', date, doc)
        await message.document.download(destination_file=path)
        print('Файлы сохранены на сервер!')
```

пробовал сделать циклом через album
он сохраняет если 3 фото в альбоме, он сохраняет 1 фото 3 раза.

```
"date": 1662022385, "media_group_id": "13296179083024154", "photo": [{"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAIH62MQcvHEGLH0wRIBiihhdD9MxNlbAAIPxjEb0ZiASLuYRzNXYeU_AQADAgADcwADKQQ", "file_unique_id": "AQADD8YxG9GYgEh4", "file_size": 1157, "width": 90, "height": 67}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAIH62MQcvHEGLH0wRIBiihhdD9MxNlbAAIPxjEb0ZiASLuYRzNXYeU_AQADAgADbQADKQQ", "file_unique_id": "AQADD8YxG9GYgEhy", "file_size": 16977, "width": 320, "height": 240}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAIH62MQcvHEGLH0wRIBiihhdD9MxNlbAAIPxjEb0ZiASLuYRzNXYeU_AQADAgADeAADKQQ", "file_unique_id": "AQADD8YxG9GYgEh9", "file_size": 84561, "width": 800, "height": 600}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAIH62MQcvHEGLH0wRIBiihhdD9MxNlbAAIPxjEb0ZiASLuYRzNXYeU_AQADAgADeQADKQQ", "file_unique_id": "AQADD8YxG9GYgEh-", "file_size": 156370, "width": 1280, "height": 960}]}>, , "date": 1662022385, "media_group_id": "13296179083024154", "photo": [{"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAIH7GMQcvEu2bYEUdR4JzTdOuzhS4JYAAIQxjEb0ZiASNTlSv3zqkSFAQADAgADcwADKQQ", "file_unique_id": "AQADEMYxG9GYgEh4", "file_size": 1254, "width": 90, "height": 67}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAIH7GMQcvEu2bYEUdR4JzTdOuzhS4JYAAIQxjEb0ZiASNTlSv3zqkSFAQADAgADbQADKQQ", "file_unique_id": "AQADEMYxG9GYgEhy", "file_size": 18332, "width": 320, "height": 240}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAIH7GMQcvEu2bYEUdR4JzTdOuzhS4JYAAIQxjEb0ZiASNTlSv3zqkSFAQADAgADeAADKQQ", "file_unique_id": "AQADEMYxG9GYgEh9", "file_size": 87098, "width": 800, "height": 600}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAIH7GMQcvEu2bYEUdR4JzTdOuzhS4JYAAIQxjEb0ZiASNTlSv3zqkSFAQADAgADeQADKQQ", "file_unique_id": "AQADEMYxG9GYgEh-", "file_size": 154562, "width": 1280, "height": 960}]}>, , "date": 1662022385, "media_group_id": "13296179083024154", "photo": [{"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAIH7WMQcvGCEVfvBuXOar9R0xs2EkkPAAIRxjEb0ZiASJDnbZY-iSXfAQADAgADcwADKQQ", "file_unique_id": "AQADEcYxG9GYgEh4", "file_size": 998, "width": 90, "height": 67}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAIH7WMQcvGCEVfvBuXOar9R0xs2EkkPAAIRxjEb0ZiASJDnbZY-iSXfAQADAgADbQADKQQ", "file_unique_id": "AQADEcYxG9GYgEhy", "file_size": 13856, "width": 320, "height": 240}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAIH7WMQcvGCEVfvBuXOar9R0xs2EkkPAAIRxjEb0ZiASJDnbZY-iSXfAQADAgADeAADKQQ", "file_unique_id": "AQADEcYxG9GYgEh9", "file_size": 66175, "width": 800, "height": 600}, {"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkBAAIH7WMQcvGCEVfvBuXOar9R0xs2EkkPAAIRxjEb0ZiASJDnbZY-iSXfAQADAgADeQADKQQ", "file_unique_id": "AQADEcYxG9GYgEh-", "file_size": 113530, "width": 1280, "height": 960}]}>]
```

выводит 3 таких массива
личную информацию стёр

Comment: Простите, а как бы вы решили ту же задачу(сохранить файлы) без машины состояний?
(какое она имеет отношение к вашему вопросу?)

Comment: По сути машина состояний здесь не играет особо роли, я просто сослался на нее , чтобы была информация что она есть, а так по сути на моменте получения фото она не играет

Comment: просто если бы просто так нужно было сохранить, я бы обработал обычным хендлером, но оно бы сохранило тоже только 1 фото, это если судить по моему коду

Comment: Эмм, а что насчёт того хендлера который группу принимает?

Comment: @oleksandrigo тоже самое, либо одно фото, либо он сохраняет первое фото, но если я 3 фото загружаю он 3 раза выгружает 1-е фото. А еще я этот хендлер который группу принимает , использую только для отправки медиа в другой чат.

Comment: по сути это и есть тот хэндлер только дополненный , я решил чтобы он сначала сохранял фото или другой контент и потому их отдельно сделать хочу чтобы сначала они сохранялись на сервере , а потом отправить в другой чат уже, потому что внутри группы не вышло.

Comment: Так у вас же есть album в ней же по идее все ваши фото. Попробуйте пройтись циклом по нему

Comment: @oleksandrigo Циклом я пробовал, но дело в том что он сохраняет 1-е фото 3 раза ну это если я допустим загружаю 3 фото, а другие просто не сохраняются

Comment: Сделайте принт album и скиньте сюда

Comment: @oleksandrigo, добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD1. Попытка сделать лучше. Правде теперь названия файлу дать не получится,  иначе нужно мучатся с расширениями файлов.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.ANY, state=FSMAdmin.photo)
async def load_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext, album: Optional[types.Message] = None):
    date = f"{datetime.date.today()}"
    if not album:
        album = [message]
    for obj in album:
        if obj.photo:
            path = os.path.join('photos', date)
            await obj.photo[-1].download(destination_dir=path)

        else:
            path = os.path.join('others', date)
            await obj[obj.content_type].download(destination_dir=path)
```

Comment: Ну подругому принт я не могу сделать))))

Comment: Он так выдает когда прошу вывести album

Comment: Все работает, благодарю!

Comment: сейчас попробую аналогично с документами и видео сделать

Comment: мне нужно еще сделать, чтобы если в альбоме будет среди фото будет видео или среди фото документ , то оно тоже срабатывало. То есть данный вариант в целом работает , но только для фото. 
`path = os.path.join('photos', date, msg.photo[-1].file_unique_id + '.jpg')
IndexError: list index out of range`
данная ошибка если среди фото будет видео

Comment: @Alex обновил попробуй

Comment: все работает как надо! Благодарен за помощь!